# Conservation of angular momentum in a system under torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

Let's say we have a particle $A$ like this
[image]
which is located in the disk $c$. Consider that the particle itself is not moving, but in general it is constrained to the semicircle $d$, in that if it would move it needs to move in that semicircle. The disk is prescribed a torque $M$. I know from the law of angular momentum that
$$ \dot{L} = \sum{M}$$
Due to the presence of the particle though, I cannot understand how will the momentum be distributed. For example consider that after some time $t$, both the particle and the curved path will have rotated to a position like this:
[image]
Given that the particle is in "rest", can someone explain to me how does it move? Generally, the answer would do best to give me clues towards finding a connection between the $\theta$ angle and the $\beta$ angle in the diagram.

Note that the diagram has been drawn randomly, basically there's no actual connection between the numbers displayed.

**Edit**.
It's possible I wasn't clear with the torque definition. The torque is prescribed around the center of the disk.

Comment: The question is unclear. Is the disk free to move? Is the disk under a torque? Does the particle itself feel a torque? Please edit the unclear parts directly instead of adding corrections at the end - the [revision history](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/231707/revisions) is always available (via the `edited ... ago` link) in case it is required.

Comment: The disk as stated in my description has a torque about it's center. The disk is rotating about it's center as can be seen on the second diagram. The particle, being part of the system, feels the moment otherwise I don't see a reason it would move. I can see all of these answers in my description. Can you please point to me a specific part of my question that is unclear? I will edit that directly.

Comment: None of the diagrams are particularly clear, and they definitely don't show (clearly enough) what you say they do. If the centre of the disk is fixed you need to specify that in the question. To be clear: the torque is applied to the disk, and the particle is completely free to move along the rail with no external torques on it? (again, make that very explicit in the question). Is the torque constant, or does it vary with time? Does the particle start at the centre? If so, why do you think it would move from there?

Comment: And, in general, a proper restructuring of the question to make it flow better would help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, the torque will be pointing out of the circle. If $\vec{r}$  is the magnitude of $\frac{d}{2}$ and points along the plane of the circle. Observe:

$\bf \vec{L}=  \vec{r}\  x\ \vec{p} \\
\vec{F}= \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}\\
\vec\tau= \frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \vec{r}\ x \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}= \vec{r}\ x \ \vec{F}
$